# Warning: Attempt to present * on * whose view is not in the window hierarchy

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

i am new to objective C and im trying to make a share button for twitter in my game. Im using spritebuilder to create all my buttons and sprites. All of my code lies in MainScene.m while my code for twitter share sheet is in ShareViewController.m

In my MainScene.m file i have a method sendToController, which using an object of shareViewController calls a method postToTwitter which is in ShareViewController.m. Due to some reason this tweetsheet is not visbile and from what i gather is that there is a window  heirachy problem which i am not able to solve.

Here is the code in MainScene.m

```
ShareViewController *_shareViewController;

@synthesize shareViewController;

(void)sendToController {
_shareViewController = [ShareViewController alloc];
[_shareViewController postToTwitter];
}
```

Here is the code for ShareViewController.m

```
@implementation ShareViewController {

MainScene *_mainSceneObj;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
_mainSceneObj.ShareViewController = self;
}

- (void)postToTwitter {

NSLog(@"in postToTwitter %d", [SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter]);
if ([SLComposeViewController isAvailableForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter])
{

    SLComposeViewController *tweetSheet = [SLComposeViewController
                                           composeViewControllerForServiceType:SLServiceTypeTwitter];

    // Sets the completion handler.  Note that we don't know which thread the
    // block will be called on, so we need to ensure that any required UI
    // updates occur on the main queue
    tweetSheet.completionHandler = ^(SLComposeViewControllerResult result) {
        switch(result) {
                //  This means the user cancelled without sending the Tweet
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultCancelled:
                break;
                //  This means the user hit 'Send'
            case SLComposeViewControllerResultDone:
                break;
        }
    };

    //  Set the initial body of the Tweet
    [tweetSheet setInitialText:@"just setting up my twttr"];

    if (![tweetSheet addImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"screen.png"]]) {
        NSLog(@"Unable to add the image!");
    }

    if (![tweetSheet addURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://twitter.com/"]]){
        NSLog(@"Unable to add the URL!");
    }

    //  Presents the Tweet Sheet to the user
    [self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:NO completion:^{
        NSLog(@"Tweet sheet has been presented.");
    }];    }

}
```

Comment: Is this `ShareViewController currently being displayed on screen at the time you call `[self presentViewController:tweetSheet animated:NO completion:^{`?

Comment: No, but the NSLog "in postToTwitter" does print

Comment: The error is clear. You are trying to present the `SLComposeViewController` from your `ShareViewController` but your `ShareViewController` isn't in view. You can't do that. You must present a view controller from a currently visible view controller.

Comment: but thats what i tried to do in sendToController method since MainScene is the currently visible view controller. Im creating a view with its class as ShareViewController

Comment: But in `sendToController` you simply create a new view controller (`ShareViewController`) without showing it. Then this undisplayed view controller attempts to present the `SLComposeViewController` from itself. As I've said (and as the error says), an undisplayed view controller can't present another view controller. You need to present the `SLComposeViewController` from a view controller that is actually already displayed on screen.

Comment: the thing is my MainScene has CCNode as its Interface and if i try to make the tweet sheet method in the Mainscene i get an error that "there is no interface for presentViewController", thus i need to change the interface from CCNode to UIViewController. Which will ruin the entire program. This was the reason for creating a new class. I was hoping that this new class would create and present a UIView when needed and then remove it. If that makes any sense.

Comment: What's CCNode? Is that Cocoas2D or whatever? It sounds like you need a whole new question that asks about the proper way to present a view controller (specifically an `SLComposeViewController`) from such an app.

Comment: CCNode is a cocoas2D class that is inherited by my MainScene class. Since im using Spritebuilder to create my scenes instead of Storyboard i have to implement all the views using code while spritebuilder handles the visual and physics part. That is why im not able to control the heirachy of the Views so easily.